# Error using mysql_query() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My Code looks like below.

```
$var = 'ID="'. mysql_real_escape_string($data[0]).'" AND SYS="'.mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]). '" AND TITLE="'.mysql_real_escape_string($data[1]).'"';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE '. $var;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

In the where condition, TITLE when using a single quote(') I am facing the below error even though the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function is being used.

The error thrown is

```
Resource id #5You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Created', 'Test', 'Test', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', ' at line 25
```

Comment: post your table columns

Comment: You posted the SELECT query while it's painfully obvious that this is an INSERT/UPDATE error..

Comment: problem in not in above query. may be there is another `insert query`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but I know it will help. I highly recommend using either PDO or MySQLi from now on for all your database calls. All of PHP's mysql_* functions have officially been deprecated.

Comment: try to echo error like this  `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Problem1 ".mysql_error());`

Comment: Are you sure the error you posted is from the query you posted? Doesn't seems like..

Answer (score 0):

after your dumping looks like you have problem with apostroph

you may change your quotes like that

```
  $var = "ID='". mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."' AND SYS='".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2]). "' AND TITLE='".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."' ";
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE ". $var;
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

$finalvar=stripslashes($var);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE '. $finalvar;

Comment: The array variable data are as follows ID="12345" SYS="Test" TITLE="Test's Created". Where the TTILE is escaped as "Test\'s Created"

Comment: Hello Rajesh, I am facing the same error after using the stripslashes() also.

Answer (score -1):

Try dumping your SQL query in its compete form right before it is sent.
You'll be able to spot the error that way.

Comment: when i dump it the sql looks like this SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ID="123456" AND SYS="Test" AND TITLE="Test\'s Created"

Comment: I am still facing the error even after escaping the single quote.